# TypeLib name in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2010, delphi-2007, typelib

When editing a type library for a COM DLL, it appears that in Delphi 2007, the type library name is always set to the name of the project. If I go and change that name, the change is ignored and eventually resets to the project name. Back in Delphi 7 I could specify the name of the type library.

What is the expected behavior? Should we expect to still be able to specify the name of a type library for a COM DLL? If so, what am I doing wrong?